# How to jest spyOn a commonJS default export

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is it possible to jest.spyOn a default export so that I can call the mockImplementation method to change what the function does before each test?

```
// code.js
module.exports = () => {
  // some irrelevant code I want to rewrite with a mock
};
```

```
// test
const code = require('./code.js');

const mockCode = jest.spyOn(code, 'default'); // this line doesn't work with the error: "Cannot spy the default property because it is not a function; undefined given instead"

it('some test', async () => {
  mockCode.mockImplementationOnce(() => { console.log('test') });

});
```

I've also tried to use jest.mock() unsuccessfully:

```
const code = require('./code');

jest.mock('./code',
    () => () => {
        console.log('test');
    }
);

it('some test', async () => {
  code.mockImplementationOnce(() => { console.log('test2') }); // error

});
```

Comment: CommonJS doesn't have 'default' export, this is exclusively ESM concept. Use jest.mock.

Comment: Hmm I've tried jest.mock, and it works, but only to set the mock implementation one time for all the tests in the file - I need some way to change the implementation before each test. When I tried to require() the jest.mock'd function and call .mockImplementation() on it during a test, it errored saying the import is not a function.

Comment: That's because you don't use spies, it should be `jest.mock('./code', () => jest.fn())`. This can likely be done with automock, `jest.mock('./code')`.